# NoMethodError 'exitstatus' while using Paperclip with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, paperclip, nomethoderror

I'm trying to use paperclip to handle file uploads in my Rails app. I'm currently running Paperclip 2.4.1 on Rails 3.0.9, running a WEBrick server on sqlite3.

The form worked fine before adding the file upload portion, but after following the quickstart instructions in the Paperclips docs (http://rdoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.4.1/file/README.md), upon form submission I get the following error:

```
undefined method `exitstatus' for nil:NilClass 
at app/controllers/shows_controller.rb:62:in `create'
```

Here's the code for my model:

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
  has_attached_file :thumb, 
                :styles => { :thumb => "150x150>" },
                :url => "/images/:id/thumb.:extension"

  validates_attachment_presence :thumb
  validates_presence_of :title 
  validates_presence_of :start_date 
  validates_presence_of :end_date
  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_presence_of :blurb 
  validates_presence_of :location

  def self.current
    where("shows.end_date > ?", Time.new).first
  end

  def self.thumb
    image_tag self.thumb.url(:thumb)
  end

end
```

The create method for my controller:

```
def create

@show = Show.create(params[:show])

respond_to do |format|
  if @show.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@show, :notice => 'Show was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @show, :status => :created, :location => @show }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @show.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

(Line 62 is the @show = Show.create(params[:show] line))

My form:

```
<%= form_for @show, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <% if @show.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@show.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this show from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @show.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :start_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_date %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :end_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :blurb %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :blurb %>
  </div>  
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :location %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :thumb %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :thumb %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And the full stack trace:

```
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
cocaine (0.2.0) lib/cocaine/command_line.rb:35:in `run'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip.rb:102:in `run'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/geometry.rb:20:in `from_file'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb:35:in `initialize'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/processor.rb:33:in `new'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/processor.rb:33:in `make'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:397:in `post_process_styles'
activemodel (3.0.9) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:295:in `inject'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:396:in `each'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:396:in `inject'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:396:in `post_process_styles'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:139:in `each'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/ordered_hash.rb:139:in `each'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:392:in `post_process_styles'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:386:in `post_process'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run_thumb_post_process_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/callback_compatibility.rb:54:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:385:in `post_process'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run_post_process_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/callback_compatibility.rb:54:in `run_paperclip_callbacks'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:384:in `post_process'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:142:in `assign'
paperclip (2.4.2) lib/paperclip.rb:335:in `thumb='
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/base.rb:1564:in `send'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/base.rb:1564:in `attributes='
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `each'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/base.rb:1560:in `attributes='
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/base.rb:1412:in `initialize'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/base.rb:502:in `new'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/base.rb:502:in `create'
app/controllers/shows_controller.rb:62:in `create'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:441:in `_run__918721632__process_action__524098549__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `action'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:68:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
C:/Rails/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
railties (3.0.9) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

I wasn't able to find any instance of this error elsewhere relating to paperclip; It looks like its bubbling up from within Rails somewhere; any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the command, that is run with cocaine is not correct. Have you configured paperclip's command path with `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"` and installed ImageMagick in this path?

You can find out where ImageMagick is with `which convert`. This should yield the path to the convert binary of ImageMagick - in my case `/usr/local/bin/convert`